# Change text selection color

Tags: user-interface, ios6, uitextview, selection

I suspect it's not possible to change the text selection (and preferably handle) color in iOS 6 (specifically in `UITextView`).

But just to be sure, I wanted to ask. Googling didn't lead me to anything useful, so if anybody has a definite answer, I'd be delighted to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can do it like this:

```
 UIColor *color = [UIColor blackColor];
 textField.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:placeholderText attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color}];
```

failing that look [here](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.in/2011/03/attributed-strings-in-ios.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I was talking about `UITextView`, not `UITextField`. Also, I want to change the selection color while retaining everything text selection entails (loupe, handles, etc.) - this is not about restyling some part of the text.